# How to handle less files in Web Optimization when running in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, optimization, web, dotless

I'm using Web Optimization and dotLess to bundle and transform less files to css.

When running in debug mode Web Optimization is not using the bundled file but referring to the original files which is fine, except that I now have links to the original untransformed less files in my html document.

Is there a way to always run the less transformation for the bundle where I have my less files?

I know I can set the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations to true, but this will turn on the bundling for all my bundles incl. javascript bundles, which I don't want.

From this question [Why is MVC4 @Styles.Render() not behaving as expected in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190339/why-is-mvc4-styles-render-not-behaving-as-expected-in-debug-mode) I can see that I can refer to the bundled less file manually if in debug mode, but it's not the most elegant solution i think.